# Org-mode: Verse blocks in LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, latex, latex-header

[in this chapter of org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Verse-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html), there is a tutorial on how to export a latex file with some features of `verse` package, such as line-counting and centralization. The example given is a poem by Shakespeare:

> #+ATTR_LATEX: :center t :latexcode \color{red} :lines 5
> #+ATTR_LATEX: :versewidth Feed’st thy light’s flame with self-substantial fuel,
> #+BEGIN_VERSE
> From fairest creatures we desire increase,
> That thereby beauty’s rose might never die,
> But as the riper should by time decease
> His tender heir might bear his memory
> But thou, contracted to thine own bright eyes,
> Feed’st thy light’s flame with self-substantial fuel,
> Making a famine where abundance lies,
> Thyself thy foe, to thy sweet self too cruel.
> Thou that art now the world’s fresh ornament,
> And only herald to the gaudy spring,
> Within thine own bud buriest thy content,
> And, tender churl, mak’st waste in niggardly.
> Pity the world, or else this glutton be,
> To eat the world’s due, by the grave and thee.
> #+END_VERSE

This, however, doesn't work when I try it. I of course added `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{verse}` before it, but still... doesn't work. I also tried `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{verse.sty}` instead, but then it displays: `file [...] wasn't produced "See "Org PDF LaTEx Output" for details".`

Comment: "doesn't work" means what exactly? It compiles into a `pdf` but you don't see the line numbers/it is not centered/it is not colored red? Or something else? FWIW, after installing the `texlive-verse` package and fixing an apparent bug in the `verse.sty` that was installed, it all works fine for me. Before I fixed the bug, the compilation failed with the error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \theHpoemline already defined.` which I fixed by changing  the `\newcommand` on line 34 of `verse.sty` to a `\renewcommand`. I have no idea who defined it originally, so this is a workaround, not a fix.

Comment: Yes, it compiles without numbers etc. 
I use Miktex; I checked it and the verse-package is installed. Yet, it compiles as if it weren't installed.

Comment: Check the `.tex` file and make sure there is a `\usepackage{verse}` line in the preamble. Check the rest of the file too and see if it makes sense: in particular, does it include `\begin{verse}...\end{verse}` and the `\poemlines{5} \color{red}` macro calls?

Comment: So, `\usepackage{verse}` is there, as well as `\begin{verse}...\end{verse}`.  But `\poemlines{5} \color{red}` is absent. 
I'm uninstalling MikTex and installing Texlive to see if this is the problem.

Comment: It's Org mode that produces the TeX file, so if something is missing in the TeX file, then Org mode is the culprit. The TeX processor takes the TeX file produces by Org mode as input, so it can not be held responsible.

Comment: Is line 34 `\newcommand{\getmodulo@vs}{\bgroup` ?

Comment: In any case I edited `\newcommand{\getmodulo@vs}{\bgroup` and still Emacs displays "PDF file produced with errors" and no line numbers etc. are seen. I asked a friend of mine to try the code and the same happens: error and no line numbers / etc.

Comment: No, it was `\newcommand*{\theHpoemline}{\arabic{verse@envctr}.\arabic{poemline}}`. In my version, the `\getmodulo@vs` definition is line 56.

Comment: So, it is not compiling with errors anymore; but still, no numbers or centering etc. I checked the tex file produced and there's no `\poemlines` or anything. Only `\begin{verse}`

Comment: You need to debug the Org mode LaTeX exporter then: what version of Org mode are you using? Also check that there is no empty line between the `#+ATTR` lines and the `#+BEGIN_VERSE`

Comment: I thank you for the help, but I think I have no need to go further on this. I can easily set lines and centring with latex code ipsis litteris. Changing that line of verse.sty corrected the bug of "pdf file produced with errors". So I am okay for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{verse}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \settowidth{\versewidth}{And the dish ran away with the spoon.}

#+OPTIONS: todo:nil date:nil toc:nil

* A Verse

#+ATTR_LATEX: :center t :latexcode \itshape
#+BEGIN_VERSE
Hey Diddle Diddle
The cat and the fiddle,
The cow jumped over the moon.
The little dog laughed,
To see such sport,
And the dish ran away with the spoon.
#+END_VERSE
```